# Trouble with Email Attachment in mail()

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to email an image on my server as an attachment. To accomplish this task, I used the following PHP script which grabs a JPG (called "php.jpg") located in a directory called "screenshots" from my server and sends it as an attachment.

```
<?php

$path = "screenshots/php.jpg";
$fp = fopen($path, 'r');
do //we loop until there is no data left
{
        $data = fread($fp, 8192);
        if (strlen($data) == 0) break;
        $content .= $data;
      } while (true);
$content_encode = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));


$mime_boundary = "<<<--==+X[".md5(time())."]";

$headers .= "From: Automatic <an.e.mail@domain.net>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "To: SomeName <me@gmail.com>\r\n"; 

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
$headers .= " boundary=\"".$mime_boundary."\"";

$message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$message .= "\r\n";
$message .= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n";

$message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$message .= "\r\n";
$message .= "Email content and what not: \r\n";
$message .= "This is the file you asked for! \r\n";
$message .= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n";

$message .= "Content-Type: image/jpeg;\r\n";
$message .= " name=\"php.jpg\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n";
$message .= " filename=\"php.jpg\"\r\n";
$message .= "\r\n";
$message .= $content_encode;
$message .= "\r\n";
$message .= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n";

$ok = mail("me@gmail.com", "file by email", $message, $headers);
```

Overall, the script works. I receive an email in my inbox containing the message text specified above and a JPG attachment. Stack Overflow won't let me post a photo because I'm new, but a screenshot of the message is available here:  http://i48.tinypic.com/xfuee0.png

My problem occurs when I try to view the attachment. Clicking the attachment simply opens a new browser window and displays a missing image icon.

Do you see any problems with my script that would prevent the image from appearing?

Any info would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the suggestions from wallyk and martinr so far (thanks guys!) but no luck. I'm wondering if maybe the mail function is fine and it's just my fopen loop that's not producing the correct image.

Any other advice anyone could provide would be appreciated. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 3):

To anyone who comes across this post in the future, the problem came from the "Content-Transfer-Encoding" which should have been set to base64.

```
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n";
```

becomes:

```
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see one possible reason why you're not seeing your image.  (There may be more (!).)

Try changing:

```
$message .= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n";
```

to

```
$message .= "--".$mime_boundary."--\r\n";
```

For the last line before the call to mail (ie the "epilogue" boundary).

Answer (score 0):

Three things jump out:

One is that the first append to variables `$content` and `$message` and `$headers` doesn't explicitly set a new value.  That is, why not

```
$headers = "From: Automatic <an.e.mail@domain.net>\r\n";
```

instead of like you have:

```
$headers .= "From: Automatic <an.e.mail@domain.net>\r\n";
```

That eliminates the possibility that some leftover stuff is hanging out in the variables.

The second is that there is `\r\n` instead of plain `\n` which should work on every system, even Windows.  I doubt this is a problem though.

Third is the closing mime boundary isn't the same as the open.

Comment: According to RFC 822, \r\n is the correct way to end header fields.